# Creating column based on other row value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have 3 columns Id,item similar_item_id

Ex:

```
Id. Item. Similar_item_id
1.  Pen.      [2,1]
2.  Book.     [1,4]
3. Phone.     4
4.  Laptop.   3
```

I want to create a new column named similar_item name instead of its Id
Like

Similar_item

Book,pen
Pen, laptop
Laptop
Phone

How can I create this new column in dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this , it is not fast than the explode , but more easy to understand

```
df['out'] = df.Similar_item_id.\
                  apply(lambda x : df.set_index('Id.').loc[x,'Item.'].tolist() 
                                                if type(x)==list 
                                                else df.set_index('Id.').loc[x,'Item.'] )
0      [Book., Pen.]
1    [Pen., Laptop.]
2            Laptop.
3             Phone.
Name: Similar_item_id, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) using a mapper from the `Id.` and `Item.` columns, and then [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) back to a `list`:

```
df['similar_item'] = (
    df['Similar_item_id'].explode()
        .map(dict(zip(df['Id.'], df['Item.'])))
        .groupby(level=0).agg(list)
)
```

`df`:

```
   Id.    Item. Similar_item_id     similar_item
0  1.0     Pen.          [2, 1]    [Book., Pen.]
1  2.0    Book.          [1, 4]  [Pen., Laptop.]
2  3.0   Phone.               4        [Laptop.]
3  4.0  Laptop.               3         [Phone.]
```

---

Or conditionally based on length:

```
df['similar_item'] = (
    df['Similar_item_id'].explode()
        .map(dict(zip(df['Id.'], df['Item.'])))
        .groupby(level=0).agg(lambda g: list(g) if len(g) > 1 else g)
)
```

```
   Id.    Item. Similar_item_id     similar_item
0  1.0     Pen.          [2, 1]    [Book., Pen.]
1  2.0    Book.          [1, 4]  [Pen., Laptop.]
2  3.0   Phone.               4          Laptop.
3  4.0  Laptop.               3           Phone.
```

---

DataFrame constructor:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id.': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0],
    'Item.': ['Pen.', 'Book.', 'Phone.', 'Laptop.'],
    'Similar_item_id': [[2, 1], [1, 4], 4, 3]
})
```